# Complex case statement-If end date is null then take the previous phase

Tags: sql, oracle, case-statement

If end date is null then take the previous phase

```
Contract_no     Contract_phase      end_date 
100     Draft           01/01/2020
100     Review          01/02/2020
100     Executed        01/03/2020
100     Completed

200     draft           01/01/2020
200     Review          01/02/2020
200     Executed

300     draft           01/01/2020
300     Review          01/02/2020
300     Executed        01/03/2020
300     Completed       01/04/2020

select Contract_no,Contract_phase
where completion date between 01/01/2020 and 01/04/2020
```

I am pulling these contracts by end dates.There are situations where 
end date is null when last phase is not yet closed in the system.
The correct phase is not picked because
of the null end date.Client wants us to pick the previous phase if 
current phase has null end date.
How do i make it pick the previous phase in this case.

Comment: Please add some sample data with your expected output from them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to aggregate here:

```
SELECT
    Contract_no
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Contract_no
HAVING
    MAX(end_date) BETWEEN date '2020-01-01' AND date '2020-04-01';
```

This should work, because `MAX` by default would just ignore `NULL` values, so the previous phase's date would be used in case a later one be missing.  This assumes, by the way, that all phases would occur in chronological order.

Comment: Thanks ,let me try,Will have to order them by date first.